# Доступ к символам в строке

Tags: php, строки

Есть пременная `$count` содержащая рандомное целое число. Необходимо привести слово в соответствие к числу, например: если `$count=21`, то 21 **год**, если `$count=113`, то 113 **лет**. Думаю нужно получить последние 2 символа из числа и в соответсвии к ним поставить различные формы слова с помощью switch, что-то типа:

```
switch((string)$count{позиции_последних_двух_символов})  {
case
...
}
```

Собственно каким способом проще всего решить  задачу, если заранее не известно двухзначное число или ещё скольких_то_там_значное. Как получить последние две цифры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гугль в помощь!

```
function declension($digit,$expr,$onlyword=false)
{
        if(!is_array($expr)) $expr = array_filter(explode(' ', $expr));
        if(empty($expr[2])) $expr[2]=$expr[1];
        $i=preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/s','',$digit)%100; //intval не всегда корректно работает
        if($onlyword) $digit='';
        if($i>=5 && $i<=20) $res=$digit.' '.$expr[2];
        else
        {
                $i%=10;
                if($i==1) $res=$digit.' '.$expr[0];
                elseif($i>=2 && $i<=4) $res=$digit.' '.$expr[1];
                else $res=$digit.' '.$expr[2];
        }
        return trim($res);
}
```

пример:

```
echo 'Мне уже '.declension('<b>20</b>','год года лет').'!';
```

Comment: Собственно нужна была только строка с `preg_replace`... Спасибо!

Comment: аа, ну так бы в вопросе и написали бы) пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант функции с меньшим количеством букв )

```
function declension($n, $words) {
    is_array($words) or $words = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1, 3);
    19 < $n = abs($n) % 100 and $n %= 10;

    if ($n == 1) {
        return reset($words);
    }

    if ($n && $n < 5) {
        return $words[min(1, count($words) - 1)];
    }

    return end($words);
}

echo sprintf(
    "Мне %u %s. I'm Jesus!",
    $count = date('Y'),
    declension($count, 'год', 'года', 'лет')
), PHP_EOL;
```